# How can I play an audio file on intial startup of Macbook Pro

Tags: audio, automator

I have a simple Automator script that is setup to run as a login item. The Automator scripts plays a .wav file as follows:

```
afplay "/Users/Audio Files/system_alert.wav"
```

This works perfectly however I am looking to refine it to play on just the initial login of a user vs subsequent logins due to the system being either manually locked or automatically locking. I am currently running OS X 10.8.1 Mountain Lion. Is this somehow possible? I have Googled around and have not found much in the way of obvious options.

Comment: Do you want the script to run once the first time a user logs in, and then never run again for that user?

Comment: If you have the script defined as a login item in Preferences, doesn't it get called only during first login already?

Comment: I would like the script to run every time the computer is warm rebooted or cold started (upon user login). Similar to functionality of a Windows startup sound.

Comment: @patrix It does indeed but it is called _every_ time said user logs in. This is my issue, I need it to run only on the initial first login, not every time said user logs into the system again due to the system locking for security.

Comment: Do you logout the user after inactivity? Login items don't get re-executed if you just enter the screensaver password.

Comment: @patrix Yes I log the user out after inactivity. The Automator script in fact does re-execute after each login (at least on my system anyway). This is what I'm trying to eliminate or modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question. I rebuilt the automator script and compiled to .APP and re-tested. @patrix is correct in that the script does only execute upon initial login and not on subsequent unlocking of the system due to inactivity. I am not sure why it was doing so previously but the issue is resolved.